# Continuous mapping of topologies that is bijective on open sets (but need not be bijective on points)

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that:

- $(T,Opens)$ and $(T',Opens')$ are topological spaces.
- $f:T\to T'$ is a continuous function (so inverse images of open sets are open).
- Further, $f^{-1}$ induces a *bijection on open sets*, by which I mean that it is surjective and injective as a map from $Opens'$ to $Opens$.

**Question:** What is the name of this property?  Can anyone provide a reference?

Note that $f$ need be neither injective nor surjective on underlying sets.  It suffices to provide an example:

- Take $T=\{0,1\}=T'$ with the trivial topology (so the only open sets are $\varnothing$ and $\{0,1\}$).
- Take $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Then $f$ is neither injective nor surjective, but it is continuous and it does induce a bijection on open sets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for examples showing that the functor $\mathcal{O}:\mathrm{Top}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathrm{Frm}$ doesn't reflect isomorphisms, where $\mathrm{Top}$ is the category of topological spaces and $\mathrm{Frm}$ is the category of frames.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz the OP is not looking for examples. They're looking for nomenclature concerning the maps in question.

Comment: I meant OP is looking for a name of those examples. Sorry, I phrased it poorly.

Comment: @PaulSinclair [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2900329/476484) implies that if both $T, T'$ are $T_1$, then $f$ is in fact a homeomorphism. So I think the OP might study spaces with really weak separation axioms?

Comment: @PaulSinclair by the way, $\{1\}$ is not open in the topology of $T'$, both of those spaces have indiscrete topology.

Comment: @Jakobian - You are correct, I confused the discrete and indiscrete topologies.